# How can we integrate our C# code in Drupal CMS

Tags: c#, drupal, content-management-system

We have C# code, which is backend for us. Now we need it to be used in our website which is developed in Drupal.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the code does?

Comment: Problem is to access an external database and gives the UI for us, we have been given the C# code, which we are supposed to put on the thing on net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to do it. You basically have 2 options:

1. Rewrite the code in php. It may be not possible to do it however, it depends on what the code does.
2. Expose c# code as an external webservice (e.g. with WCF) and then consume the webservice. Drupal is able to do it - [more info](http://drupal.org/project/services/).

Comment: Is the following link an example of your (2.) option above?  https://drupal.org/node/308629   "Example: User login with API key using C#".  Or is it referring to an alternative approach?  (I have not yet taken the time to understand the details, just gathering initial information on ways to integrate .Net code we have with Drupal.)

Answer (score 0):

A sloppy solution would also be to display your C# page in the Drupal page with an iframe. I do also agree with empi's answer to rewrite the code in php or a web service depending on your requirement.

Answer (score -2):

You can build DLL project (class library) in C# and use the DLL as reference back in the drupal project. 
Not sure about this, and never done before. 
You better research more. 
But, the best way to use the .NET code in another application is to build the required code into DLL project and use in whichever language you want to use.

Comment: Like @empi said, I think c# as web service is more appropriate for this case.